# search for neighbors of a value in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I look for the bottom and top closest to a value

in this dataframe

```
             0            1
 1.    0.738235    0.000000    
 2.    1.210000     0.000000    
 3.    1.713830     0.031915      
 15.   7.705405   536.778378    
 16.   8.187640   649.865169    
 17.   8.710476   790.257143    
 18.   9.165625   921.343750    
 19.   9.678723  1053.531915    
 20.  10.188000  1190.200000    
 21.  10.700000  1325.523810    
 22.  11.220000  1480.300000    
 23.  11.642857  1591.285714    
 24.  12.300000  1748.142857    
 25.  12.660000  1903.200000    
 26.  13.150000  1988.666667    
 27.  13.700000  2023.000000    
 29.  14.633333  2034.000000    
 31.  15.900000  2053.000000     
 32.  14.210000  1111.000000
```

If I look for the value of `15.9`, then I want to have the nearest lower `14.633333` and the nearest higher than `15.90000`

If I look for the value of `12.3`, then I want to have the nearest lower `11.64` and the nearest higher `12.66`

I tried   :

```
df.iloc[(df[0]-value).abs().argsort()[:2]]
```

but the result was

```
 28  14.233333  2039.0    
 31  14.210000  1111.0
```

Comment: Please remember to format your code when you ask something. In general, double check your question before submitting it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible with only one query, but I am not sure how to do that, so instead you can run 2 separate queries to get the upper and lower values:

For the upper value:

```py
df.loc[df.loc[(df['0']-value)>0]['0'].idxmin()]
```

For the lower one:

```py
df.loc[df.loc[(df['0']-value)<0]['0'].idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked but I had to create the exception because if there are equal numbers but no neighbors

try:
    print(dados_import.loc[dados_import.loc[(dados_import[0]-valor)>0][0].idxmin()])
except:
    print(dados_import.loc[dados_import.loc[(dados_import[0]-valor)>=0][0].idxmin()])
try:
    print(dados_import.loc[dados_import.loc[(dados_import[0]-valor)<0][0].idxmax()])
except:
print(dados_import.loc[dados_import.loc[(dados_import[0]-valor)<=0][0].idxmax()])

Answer (score 0):

This will select all the appropriate rows even if the numbers are not unique or the value is below the minimum or above the maximum

```
def boundingRows(col, value):
    dif = col - value
    lw0 = dif < 0
    gr0 = dif > 0
    il = dif == dif[dif[lw0].idxmax()] if lw0.any() else dif == 0
    iu = dif == dif[dif[gr0].idxmin()] if gr0.any() else dif == 0
    return il | iu
df[boundingRows(df[0], 12.3)]
```